# Does the "precise representative" $f^*$ uniquely represent classes in $L^1_{loc}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The **precise representative** of a function $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R^n})$ (as for example in *Evans - Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions (2nd Ed)*) is defined as

$$ f^*(x) = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y)dy $$

where the limit exists, $0$ elsewhere (but it can be shown that the limit exists almost everywhere!).

It is true that if $f = g$ almost everywhere (i.e., $f$ and $g$ belong to the same class in $L^1_{loc}$), then $f^* = g^*$ (it follows the definition of precise representative in the aforementioned Evan's book).

**My question is**: is the converse also true? ($f^* = g^* \Rightarrow f=g$ a.e.?). If this is the case, I can conveniently think of the classes in $L^1_{loc}$ as represented by the common precise representative of any element in the class.

Comment: Try it first with $g = 0$. If $f^* = 0$, is $f =0$ a.e.?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MatthewLeingang. Actually, I don't know (although I believe so). Could you push me a bit more towards the right direction?

Comment: Ok, maybe I came up with an argument to show that indeed $f=0$ a.e. However, I'm not sure it works...

Comment: Suppose $f\ge0$ for now, fix $x$, and define $E_x(r,\varepsilon) := \{  y \in B(x,r) \mid f(y) > \varepsilon \}$. Now, $\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y)dy \ge \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\varepsilon|E_x(r,\varepsilon)|\ge0$. Now, we know that the left term goes to $0$ if $r\rightarrow0$, and for this reason we must have $|E_x(r,\varepsilon)|=o(r^n)$ for $r\rightarrow0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: I think that going on with this argument one can show that it's true. I can try and write it, but it's quite long for a comment. I would wait for your hint before I go on ^^ If I'm pointing at the wrong direction it's quite useless...

Comment: Look up the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem

Comment: Another problem may be ... $(f+g)^*$ could differ from $f^* + g^*$, even though they agree a.e.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, but I don't see how this would be a problem. Do you mean that this remark provides a counterexample to my question?

Comment: @rod Lebesgue differentiation gives $f=f^*$ and $g=g^*$ a.e., so it is immediate that $f=g$ a.e. if you assume $f^*=g^*$ a.e.

Comment: @Nick Alright, that was quite straightforward then. Thank you!

Comment: The remark shows the map $f \mapsto f^*$ is not linear.  Although you select one function from each equivalence class, thet selection does not respect the addition operation.

Comment: @GEdgar Got it, in this sense it's "dangerous" to think of the class of $f$ as its unique representative $f^*$?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to give myself an answer. However, **the fastest way to see this is definitley, as it has been suggested in the comments, passing through Lebesgue-Besicovitch differentiation theorem**, which assures that $f^*=f$ a.e. I am still posting it; please feel free to comment or correct me.

Our thesis is: $f^* = g^* \Rightarrow f=g$ a.e.

Let's suppose for simplicity that $f\ge0$, and $g=0$ for the moment; the thesis becomes $f^*=0 \Rightarrow f=0$ a.e.
Let $x$ be an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ fixed.

For all $\varepsilon>0$ set
$ E_x(r,\varepsilon) := \{ y \in B(x,r) \mid f(y) > \varepsilon \} $. Then we have:
$$ \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} fdy \ge \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \varepsilon |E_x(r,\varepsilon)| \ge 0 $$
And the left term goes to $0$ when $r\rightarrow0^+$, which implies that $|E_x(r,\varepsilon)| = o(r^n)$.

Now, for simplicity set $n=1$ (but the prove doesn't seem to be much harder in the general case). We take some interval $[a,b]$ and we show that $f=0$ a.e. on $[a,b]$. More precisely, setting $G := \{ y \in [a,b] \mid f(y)>0 \}$, let's show that $|G| = 0$.

For every $k \in 2(\mathbb{N}+1)$, let's split $[a,b]$ as $k$ intervals of length $\frac{2}{k}$: $a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_{k/2}=b$ such that $[a,b] = \bigcup_{j=1}^k I_j$ (and $|I_j| = \frac{2}{k}$). Set $ G_j := \{ y \in I_j \mid f(y)>0 \} $. Then;

$$ |G| = \sum_{j=1}^{k/2} |G_j| = \sum_{j=1}^{k/2} o\Big(\frac{1}{k}\Big) \rightarrow_{k\rightarrow+\infty} 0 $$

Now, if $n>1$ we pick rectangles instead of intervals.

Finally, for the general case $f^* = g^*$, we got:

$$ 0 = f^* - g^* = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{|\{B(x,r)\}|} \int_{B(x,r)}\Big(f-g\Big)dy \Rightarrow (f-g)^*=0 \Rightarrow f-g=0 $$

Comment: I don't quite follow this proof.  You picked an arbitrary $x$ at the beginning, so you don't know that the averages converge to $0$ (or anything) near $x$.  They may diverge.

Comment: Also, even if you did have that convergence of the averages everywhere, you would not necessarily have uniform convergence, so you cannot meaningfully write $\sum_{j=1}^{k/2} |G_j| = \sum_{j=1}^{k/2} o\Big(\frac{1}{k}\Big)$.

Comment: Lastly, you introduced sets $E_x(r,\varepsilon)$ in the first half of the proof but then completely forgot about $\varepsilon$ in the second half of the proof, where you seem to be tacitly using "$|E_x(r,\varepsilon)| = o(r^n)$" from earlier on the sets $G_j$, which do not arise as $E_x(r,\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.